# npm behind a proxy fails with status 403

Tags: http, node.js, proxy, npm

I'm trying to run *npm* behind a proxy. I've tried both entering the proxy directly or through *Authoxy*:

```
npm config set proxy http://localhost:8999
npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:8999
```

Regardless of which proxy I use, I always end up with the same error when running `npm search`:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'search' ]
npm info using npm@1.1.45
npm info using node@v0.8.4
npm verb config file /Users/xxx/.npmrc
npm verb config file /usr/local/etc/npmrc
npm verb config file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
npm WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient
npm verb url raw /-/all
npm verb url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './-/all' ]
npm verb url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
npm info retry registry request attempt 1 at 09:48:47
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, sutatusCode=403
npm info retry registry request attempt 2 at 09:48:57
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, sutatusCode=403
npm info retry registry request attempt 3 at 09:49:57
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, sutatusCode=403
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onConnect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/tunnel.js:148:19)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:185:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1383:11)
npm ERR!     at TCP.onread (net.js:410:27)
```

The command always fails with `sutatusCode` [sic!] **403** - which means unauthorized. I have set up Authoxy to not require a username/password. The same error happens when I bypass Authoxy and provide the real proxy credentials for our NTLM proxy in the form of http:// user:pass@proxy:port.

How can I make this work through the proxy?

**Update**

I have created an issue on the NPM project to report this: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2866

Comment: try npm config set strict-ssl false

Answer (score 158, accepted):

OK, so within minutes after posting the question, I found the answer myself here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2119#issuecomment-5321857

The issue seems to be that npm is not that great with HTTPS over a proxy. Changing the registry URL from HTTPS to HTTP fixed it for me:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I still have to provide the proxy config (through Authoxy in my case), but everything works fine now.

Seems to be a common issue, but not well documented. I hope this answer here will make it easier for people to find if they run into this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I have this error: "Error: Invalid protocol"

Comment: Worked for me using this answer along with @tedyyu proxy answer (below as I write this).

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you are using 'sudo' with the 'npm' command then you'll also need to use 'sudo' for the 'config set' commands.  This took me a bit to figure out, although it seems obvious now.

Comment: There's one more wrinkle here that I've recently come across. Some packages will call `cache add spec package-name@tarball-url`. Presumably, the tarball url comes via `npm view` which will be `https` even if you have set your registry to use `http`. I have not found a solution to this yet. Anyone else?

Comment: This solution worked for me, until it arrived to some dependencies in which the same error appears despite being using HTTP

Comment: Work for me with https not http.

Comment: Very Nice. Works perfectly.

Comment: This was the weirdest problem ever.  Just started one morning.  This answer got me back on track!

Answer (score 32):

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

credit goes to http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy.

Comment: As you might have seen, this is the first change that I made - see the first couple of lines in my question. It did not work for me, probably due to the kind of proxy we're running here. I had to additionally change the registry address to use HTTP instead of HTTPS (see my answer).

Comment: worked perfectly for me on Windows 7 box on my corporate network

Comment: As with default:
npm config set https-proxy registry.npmjs.org
npm config set proxy registry.npmjs.org

Answer (score 12):

If you need to provide a username and password to authenticate at your proxy, this is the syntax to use:

```
npm config set proxy http://usr:pwd@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://usr:pwd@host:port
```

Comment: this seems to be storing the password in plaintext, which is a terrible idea. I'm not sure if it is also transmitted in plaintext via http?

Answer (score 8):

If anyone else ends up breaking their proxy config settings go to your **.npmrc**, to type in the settings. *This file is located at your node root folder level.*

Here's whats my corrected file looks like:

```
#proxy = http://proxy.company.com:8080
https-proxy = https://proxy.company.com:8080 
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I read the registry that npm using:

```
 npm config get registry
```

and I got

```
http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

then I had just changed `http` to `https` like this:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to security violations, organizations may have their own repositories.

set your local repo as below.

npm config set registry https://yourorg-artifactory.com/

I hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and finally it was resolved by disconnecting from all VPN .

Comment: I use ZScaler. The same solution worked for me.
Installation went through fine while ZScaler was being restarted.

Answer (score 1):

For those using Jenkins or other CI server: it matters *where* you define your proxies, especially when they're different in your local development environment and the CI environment. In this case:

- don't define proxies in project's .npmrc file. Or if you do, be sure to override the settings on CI server.
- any other proxy settings might cause `403 Forbidden` with little hint to the fact that you're using the wrong proxy. Check your `gradle.properties` or such and fix/override as necessary.

TLDR: define proxies not in the project but on the machine you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

On windows 10, do

```
npm config edit
```

This will open config file in a text editor. Delete all the set proxy variables by user and only let default values stay.

```
;;;;
; npm userconfig file
; this is a simple ini-formatted file
; lines that start with semi-colons are comments.
; read `npm help config` for help on the various options
;;;;

--->Delete everything proxy settings from here.

;;;;
; all options with default values
;;;;
```

Close and save. Try again. That's what worked for me in my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

On windows10, create this file. Worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Avoid the ssl check is risky and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Though you're right @Alex, the mentioned urls aren't https, so SSL is not applicable there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was failing because I was connected to office VPN. After disconnecting from VPN it was working fine.

Answer (score -1):

my [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) expired recently. I generated a new one, and replaced the old in `.zshrc`.
Encountered same error as above when ran `yarn install`.

Authorizing token with SSO fixed it for me.
[image]