# How to fix SSL certificate error when running Npm on Windows?

Tags: npm

When I try to install a package with npm, it doesn't work. After a long wait, I eventually get an error 'tunneling socket could not be established, sutatusCode=403'.

```
$ npm install coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, sutatusCode=403
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onConnect (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\tunnel.js:148:19)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:193:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1393:11)
npm ERR!     at TCP.onread (net.js:403:27)
```

However, when I browse to that same URL in my web browser (Google Chrome) it loads fine (see footnote). https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script

What's going wrong?

---

While I happen to use a https proxy, I'm confident this isn't the problem. I've configured the environment variable `https_proxy` (per the npm [user guide](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html)). I know the environment variable is correct, because the Python package manager `pip` follows it correctly.

I believe the problem relates to SSL certificates, because if I download that URL with `wget`, I get an explicit error about certificates

```
$ wget https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
--2012-12-17 12:14:07--  https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
Resolving corpproxy... 10.254.215.35
Connecting to corpproxy|10.254.215.35|:8080... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify registry.npmjs.org's certificate, issued by `/C=US/ST=CA/L=Oakland/O=npm/OU=npm Certificate Authority/CN=npmCA/emailAddress=i@izs.me':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to registry.npmjs.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

How can I fix this? Without compromising security.

---

I used to get SSL certificate errors in my web browser too, until I installed the 'npmCA' certificate as a 'trusted root certification authority' in Control Panel's Internet Options (screenshot [image] )

---

Edit: I tried an *insecure* workaround per https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html#strict-ssl

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Yet it still times out with the same error

```
$ npm install coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, sutatusCode=403
```

Comment: This is similar to the issue I'm having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773509/npm-behind-a-proxy-fails-with-status-403/11773612

Comment: Hi. See also https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2728

Comment: Entering "npm set strict-ssl false" solved a problem

Answer (score 250, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Just run this and don't disable your security:

*Replace existing certs*

```
# Windows/MacOS/Linux 
npm config set cafile "<path to your certificate file>"

# Check the 'cafile'
npm config get cafile
```

**or** *extend existing certs*

Set this environment variable to extend pre-defined certs:
`NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` to `"<path to certificate file>"`

### Full story

I've had to work with npm, pip, maven etc. behind a corporate firewall under Windows - it's not fun. I'll try and keep this platform agnostic/aware where possible.

### HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY

`HTTP_PROXY` & `HTTPS_PROXY` are environment variables used by lots of software to know where your proxy is. Under Windows, lots of software also uses your OS specified proxy which is a totally different thing. That means you can have Chrome (which uses the proxy specified in your Internet Options) connecting to the URL just fine, but npm, pip, maven etc. not working because they use HTTPS_PROXY (except when they use HTTP_PROXY - see later). Normally the environment variable would look something like:

```
http://proxy.example.com:3128
```

But you're getting a [403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) which suggests you're not being authenticated against your proxy. If it is basic authentication on the proxy, you'll want to set the environment variable to something of the form:

```
http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:3128
```

### The dreaded NTLM

There is an HTTP status code 407 (proxy authentication required), which is the more correct way of saying it's the proxy rather than the destination server that's rejecting your request. That code plagued me for the longest time until after a lot of time on Google, I learned my proxy used [NTLM authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager). HTTP basic authentication wasn't enough to satisfy whatever proxy my corporate overlords had installed. I resorted to using [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) on my local machine (unauthenticated), then had it handle the NTLM authentication with the upstream proxy. Then I had to tell all the programs that couldn't do NTLM to use my local machine as the proxy - which is generally as simple as setting `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`. Otherwise, for npm use (as @Agus suggests):

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.com:3128
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.example.com:3128
```

### "We need to decrypt all HTTPS traffic because viruses"

After this set-up had been humming along (clunkily) for about a year, the corporate overlords decided to change the proxy. Not only that, but it would no longer use NTLM! A brave new world to be sure. But because those writers of malicious software were now delivering malware via HTTPS, the only way they could protect we poor innocent users was to man-in-the-middle every connection to scan for threats before they even reached us. As you can imagine, I was overcome with the feeling of safety.

To cut a long story short, the self-signed certificate needs to be installed into npm to avoid [`SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN`](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8129):

```
npm config set cafile "<path to certificate file>"
```

Alternatively, the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable can be set to the certificate file.

I think that's everything I know about getting npm to work behind a proxy/firewall. May someone find it useful.

**Edit**: It's a really common suggestion to turn off HTTPS for this problem either by using an HTTP registry or setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED`. These are not good ideas because you're opening yourself up to further man-in-the-middle or redirection attacks. A quick spoof of your DNS records on the machine doing the package installation and you'll find yourself trusting packages from anywhere. It may seem like a lot of work to make HTTPS work, but it is highly recommended. When you're the one responsible for allowing untrusted code into the company, you'll understand why.

**Edit 2**:
Keep in mind that setting `npm config set cafile <path>` causes npm to only use the certs provided in that file, instead of extending the existing ones with it.

If you want to extend the existing certs (e.g. with a company cert) using the environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` to link to the file is the way to go and can save you a lot of hassle. See [how-to-add-custom-certificate-authority-ca-to-nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283040/how-to-add-custom-certificate-authority-ca-to-nodejs#comment91831623_47160447)

Comment: On Windows, I had to use forward slashes:

npm config set cafile "C:/dev/Firefox/mycert.cer"

Comment: This is an awesome response -- I couldn't summarize my own headaches better concerning proxy + zscalar

Comment: laughed so hard because of "As you can imagine, I was overcome with the feeling of safety." :)

Comment: This is good info but for me it worked by inserting process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; Does it mean I'm passing my values in clear text now?

Comment: @MatthisKohli It's not in plain text, but it will allow a man-in-the-middle to use whatever certificate they want, and it will be trusted (i.e. that one MITM will have effectively clear text).

Comment: How do I get the certificate file ?

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Had to figure out where the local cert was, but after exporting and converting to `.pem` it was clear sailing.

Comment: Do you mean the ca.crt file located in the npm folder tree?

Comment: `npm config set cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` after correctly adding my Root CA worked for me, thanks!

Comment: To help you with your next problem... `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:` and `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, how correctly add root certificate to ca-certificates.crt ?

Comment: That proxy config did the tricket for me. Great to have several options for solutions.

Answer (score 36):

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

solved the issue for me.
In this case both my agent and artifact depository are behind a private subnet on aws cloud

Comment: This solution will set ssl off for all the installs which  is a security risk. Setting the npm registry is the actual solution npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: This works fine for me in windows 10. Quick fix. thanks

Comment: Disabling security is not a real solution

Comment: @Ali could you explain more how to set registry for npmjs? like should i just run npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey this is the command "npm config set registry registry.npmjs.org"

Comment: Using this answer means you don't care for security for whatever reason. Thats not a good attitude. It only should be used to see if the TLS certificates are the issue (and offtopic: why people and software still use SSL as a term and not TLS, idk...). And then get the configuration working correctly with `strict-ssl` set to `true` again a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 34):

This problem was fixed for me by using http version of repository:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: That's a very bad solution!

Comment: @KiTO Why is it Bad. It worked for me too. Just want to know what is wrong with this...

Comment: @HaBo I'm guessing he means this is unsecure.

Comment: @KiTO It's a bad solution, agreed. But why should I have to mess with certificate issues when I just want to install some packages?

Comment: Not only bad, this is probably the most overrated answer I've ever seen. You solve a security issue by further lowering  the security level. Wow...

Comment: @Ich Because if you're behind a proxy, you're probably working on a company's network. If you're on someone else's network you've got people around you who depend on your code. If you've got people whose jobs depend on your code you don't want to open up security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @AlexTaylor I'm not behind a corporate firewall or proxy. My point was: This should be working out of the box, without any SSL-Cert configuration stuff.

Comment: I agree. It should. Hopefully this can help someone.

Comment: This is the only solution that resolved my issue. It's kind of a rock-and-a-hard place to be, either I make my connections insecure, or I don't have access to the registry through NPM. I'm behind a VPN and company firewall.  This is also a problem for jspm; I have to use the command 'jspm config strictSSL false'.  It's also a problem with ruby gems--fixed by using 'gem sources -r https://rubygems.org' and 'gem sources -a http://rubygems.org'. Is this a system admin issue or an issue with ALL off these package managers? Makes me believe it's a system-admin configuration problem I can't control.

Comment: This answer is correct. There are some cases when you're behind corporate proxy mess with own certificate chain on top of others and there is no other way (apart of disabling certs at all) than this (especially when they're not giving you admin rights). This sounds like npm bug which doesn't properly loads the proper settings from the system. But for the sake of cross-compatibility, they won't fix the npm, so this is the result of it. People who say it's a bad answer, they've no idea what they're talking about.

Comment: @kenorb that's incorrect, you can retrace the steps your proxy takes and add those self signed certs to your chain with cafile.

Comment: It's a short term solution.

Comment: @Ich it is working out of the box, if it does not it means your system is misconfigured. In which case the solution is to fix your system, not to bypass security as this answer does.

Answer (score 9):

I happened to encounter this similar SSL problem a few days ago. The problem is your npm does not set root certificate for the certificate used by https://registry.npmjs.org.

**Solutions:**

1. Use `wget https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script --ca-certificate=./DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt` to fix wget problem
2. Use `npm config set cafile /path/to/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt` to set root certificate for your npm program.

you can download root certificate from : `https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt`

**Notice:** Different program may use different way of managing root certificate, so do not mix browser's with others.

### **Analysis:**

let's fix your `wget https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script` problem first. your snippet says:

```
        ERROR: cannot verify registry.npmjs.org's certificate,
        issued by /C=US/ST=CA/L=Oakland/O=npm/OU=npm 
       Certificate Authority/CN=npmCA/emailAddress=i@izs.me:
       Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

This means that your wget program cannot verify `https://registry.npmjs.org`'s certificate. There are two reasons that may cause this problem:

1. Your wget program does not have this domain's root certificate. The root certificate usually ship with system.
2. The domain does not pack root certificate into his certificate.

So the solution is explicitly set root certificate for `https://registry.npmjs.org`. We can use openssl to make sure that the reason bellow is the problem.

Try `openssl s_client -host registry.npmjs.org -port 443` on the command line and we will get this message (first several lines):

```
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    depth=1 /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
    verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
    verify return:0
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Fastly, Inc./CN=a.sni.fastly.net
       i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
     1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
       i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
    ---
```

This line  `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate` makes sure that `https://registry.npmjs.org` does not pack root certificate. So we Google `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` root Certificate.

Comment: If you can only provide the text base file (like for Jenkins builds), this certificate can be converted into pem: openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt -out DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem using

```
npm config set proxy http://my-proxy.com:1080
npm config set https-proxy http://my-proxy.com:1080
```

Additionally info at [node-doc](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html#https-proxy)

Answer (score 8):

I was having same issue. After some digging I realized that many post/pre-install scripts would try to install various dependencies and some times specific repositories are used. A better way is to disable certificate check for https module for nodejs that worked for me.

`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"`

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)

Comment: As mentioned already, this will not __fix__ the SSL issue, it will only by pass it. The proper way to address this is to properly configure each package (git, npm, node) to trust the proper signing certificate. If you are behind a coporate proxy, of couurse.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert certificate .cer to .pem. For that run in CMD:

openssl x509 -inform der -in C:\tmp\zScaler.cer -out C:\tmp\zScaler.pem

npm config set cafile C:\tmp\zScaler.pem

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on your proxy. Because the location provider of your install package creates its own certificate and does not buy a verified one from an accepted authority, your proxy does not allow access to the targeted host. 
I assume that you bypass the proxy when using the Chrome Browser. So there is no checking.

There are some solutions to this problem. But all imply that you trust the package provider.

Possible solutions:

1. As mentioned in other answers you can make an `http://` access which
   may bypass your proxy. That's a bit dangerous, because the man in the middle can inject malware into you downloads.
2. The `wget` suggests you to use a flag `--no-check-certificate`. This will add a proxy directive to your request. The proxy, if it understands the directive, does not check if the servers certificate is verified by an authority and passes the request. Perhaps there is a config with npm that does the same as the wget flag.
3. You configure your proxy to accept CA npm. I don't know your proxy, so I can't give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the proxy server or can convince your IT admins you could try to explicitly exclude registry.npmjs.org from SSL inspection. This should avoid users of the proxy server from having to either disable strict-ssl checking or installing a new root CA.

Answer (score -3):

This is what you can do to avoid npm and use yarn in window machine.

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false
```