# Getting UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE from NPM when installing hexo-cli

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am getting an `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` error when I try to install hexo-cli on Windows. I have tried switching to another mirror but that did not fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: Embedding the screenshot directly in the post makes it more obvious what it is about.

Answer (score 9):

Are you behind a corporate proxy? They are most likely intercepting & MiTM'ing the traffic with a self signed SSL certificate.

A hacky solution is just to turn off SSL for NPM

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

More detailed instructions can be found here: [How to fix SSL certificate error when running Npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913941/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-error-when-running-npm-on-windows)

References:

https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs#i-am-behind-a-corporate-proxy-that-uses-self-signed-ssl-certificates-to-intercept-encrypted-traffic

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101721/is-it-possible-for-corporation-to-intercept-and-decrypt-ssl-tls-traffic

Comment: How to explain about Err Windows_NT 6.1.7601?Does it means my windows version can not compatible with npm?

Comment: I try "npm set strict-ssl false", it still doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow instructions described here:

[How to fix SSL certificate error when running Npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913941/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-error-when-running-npm-on-windows)

As the author suggests, the point here to use `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable. Keep in mind that setting `npm config set cafile <path>` causes `npm` to only use the certs provided in that file, instead of extending the existing ones with it.