# Error with ionic start command

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

While issuing the below command (to start a new ionic2 project),

```
ionic start ionic-tabs-app tabs --type=ionic-angular
```

I receive the below error message,

```
[INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/
master.tar.gz)
? Downloading - failed!
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Can anyone faced such issue?. How can we overcome this issue?

Comment: maybe this is your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913941/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-error-when-running-npm-on-windows

Comment: @david R....any usefull thing you found??if you.....can u please share

Comment: @suraj Thanks for the link. I don't prefer to set the `strict_ssl` to false. Trying other suggestions specified there, so far no luck

Comment: @SaEChowdary You also facing the same issue?

Comment: not exactly but i am curious to know about this

Comment: @SaEChowdary Sure thing!. Will update the post if I found anything useful :)

Comment: Could you try to redownload ionic? "npm install -g ionic"
Or as workaround, try to disable git ssl : "git config --global http.sslVerify false"

Comment: have u checked this david https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9580

Comment: @FooBar Thanks for the answer. Tried installing ionic globally. Question about thh second suggestion, if I disable `http.sslVerify` will it compromise the security?

Comment: @SaEChowdary Thanks for the link!. I have checked that too, I'm not convinced to issue `npm config set strict-ssl false` which is the common answer given there :)

Comment: yeah i am too seeing the same thing with other links also.....

Comment: Disabling ssl can compromise security, there is a big discussion [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742)
where the other proposition is to set "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/" and last one to add a 'cafile' ...read link.

Comment: @FooBar Sure, I will go through!

Comment: @FooBar The only fruitful solution they gave is to create a `.pem` file and to set it via `npm config.. ` command, however since I don't have `openssl` here in my working environment, I'm not able to explore that. I ended up downloading the `starter kit` from the `ionic` git page, and doing the development now.

Comment: **Update**: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16868

Comment: I've tried this nice article, no luck though :(  => https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/