# How to fixed npm install and other npm command

Tags: npm

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Hostname/IP doesn’t match certificate’s altnames: “Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert’s altnames: DNS:*.smartdnsproxy.com, DNS:smartdnsproxy.com”

How to fixed? thanks

im using macbook pro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix SSL certificate error when running Npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913941/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-error-when-running-npm-on-windows)

Comment: what do you mean duplicate?? im using macbook pro

Comment: Have you read the thread and seen how you can configure a proxy? That should be applicable also on Mac OS X.