# How to fix instillation issues with npm modules on Windows 10, including node-pre-gyp? 2019

Tags: javascript, npm, node-pre-gyp

I've looked at probably 20+ questions relating to this error of installing npm modules and getting a node-pre-gyp or libxmls errors on Windows. Most of the questions are more than a year old, so thought I'd ask this in June 2019 in case there were people still having issues!

This particular error is happening with the module `excel-as-json`.

1. node version - 8.11.0
2. npm version - 5.6.0
3. Windows 10
4. I am behind a
   corporate firewall, I've set the

> `npm config set http-proxy` , `npm config set https-proxy`
>   `` npm config set registry `http://registry.npmjs.org/ ``

5. I've installed the windows-build-tools (though it only seems to install in the admin user, I copied and pasted what was installed into the non-admin user).
6. Occasionally I get an error when I try to run this with `npm install -g excel-as-json --proxy http://proxy.host.com:8080`

> gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python27", you can set the
>   PYTHON env variable. gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython
>   (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19) gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.
>   (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
>   gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)

**Please help! I've spent about 14 hours trying to trouble shoot this and I have no idea.**

```
C:\Users\User>npm install -g excel-as-json
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js

> libxmljs@0.18.8 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\libxmljs
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http

node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.8/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 400 https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.8/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(400): https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.8/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for libxmljs@0.18.8 and node@8.11.0 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 400 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.8/node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.11.0/node-v8.11.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v8.11.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--loglevel=http" "--module=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\excel-as-json\\node_modules\\libxmljs\\build\\Release\\xmljs.node" "--module_name=xmljs" "--module_path=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\excel-as-json\\node_modules\\libxmljs\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=1" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--python=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python27\\python2.7.exe"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --loglevel=http --module=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node --module_name=xmljs --module_path=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi --python=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python27\python2.7.exe' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.0\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\excel-as-json\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--loglevel" "http"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\libxmljs
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\James1.Hicks\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --loglevel=http --module=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node --module_name=xmljs --module_path=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\excel-as-json\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi --python=C:\Users\James1.Hicks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python27\python2.7.exe' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.18.8 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.18.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, this answer fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30341389/10691936

```
#For Windows/MacOS/Linux
npm config set cafile "<path to your certificate file>"

#Check the 'cafile'
npm config get cafile
```

Also I left the ssl features active

```
npm config set strict-ssl true
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ --global
```

And "node-pre-gyp" is actually using a different proxy setting than npm, it's set in the environmental variables, so under Windows I did this:

```
set https_proxy=<your proxy>
set http_proxy=<your proxy>
```