After upgrading node and npm, "npm install" hangs unless I disable strict-ssl
I upgraded my node version from 16.14.2 to 20.18.0, and npm from 8.5.0 to 10.9.0. After doing this, the command npm install hangs forever.
Things get fixed if I execute
npm set strict-ssl false

What happened? Is there anything new in npm 10 that I am missing? How do I fix this without disabling strict ssl? Do I need to generate a certificate and add it to npm? I don't even recall having / using an npm account.
By the way I am not on a corporate network, no firewalls etc. It's just me in my personal laptop (using Ubuntu) at my home's wifi

Have you looked through https://stackoverflow.com/q/13913941/1427878 yet?

@C3roe I am on ubuntu, not on windows, so I thought that issue was not relevant

Actually, I think that question has the right solution. I created an .npmrc file and added registry = 'https://registry.npmjs.org/' in it, and this fixes the problem
