# Issue installing npm on my Win7 Machine

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install the WEINRE on my win7 machine as per the instruction given in this link
http://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-2623

Note: I might be behind a firewall.

1. I installed node.js and
2. then I tried to install weinre via npm. This fails with the following error

[image]

Please help me in installing weinre so that i can go on.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "I might be behind a firewall": do you mean you are not sure, or are you sure you are behind a firewall?

Comment: @KornP Previously i had the experience with this firewall that is i was not able to clone some git repository because of my firewall. i don't know whether that firewall block this npm also.

Comment: i am in work environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do to find out the problem:

1. do an nslookup of registry.npmjs.org to find out if the address can be resolved
2. check your network settings to find out if there is a proxy configured
   If so, configure npm to use the proxy. This is how you can do this:

   `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

    npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`

Credits go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12832637/52568.

Comment: i am using proxy for my internet connection. i am new to this node and weinre, please tell me the steps to do the nslookup. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MohamedHussain If you're behind a proxy, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11773612 may help.

Comment: @KornP: Thanks for the help. now i am able to install the npm for weinre.