# While installing Jquery giving error through NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, requirejs, bower

I am installing Jquery package using nodeJs command prompt but it is giving me error.

here i did the following thing ...

1. Installed Node Js
2. I have set proxy using 'npm config set https-proxy "proxy address"'.
3. Installed bower using "npm install -g bower requirejs"
4. When i run command "bower install jquery" it is giving me following error

   C:\wamp\www\RequireBackbone>bower install jquery

   bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 1.1s

   bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 3.1s

   bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 5.2s

   bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 9.4s

Comment: Is this a problem for npm also or is it happening only on bower.

Comment: it is npm problem.. or might be proxy problem also

Comment: Can you browse net using proxy- http and https.

Comment: Try the first answer mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773509/npm-behind-a-proxy-fails-with-status-403

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to a known [issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/208) in bower. Try setting this environment variable -

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy_server>
```

Comment: hi.. This setting is already done in my system. is there any other way ?

Comment: Make sure to include the schema and the port