# npm install shows 403 Error on Ubuntu on Windows 10 behind proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, http-status-code-403, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using ubuntu on Windows 10 to install and run npm.
I downloaded nodejs using:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash 
apt-get install -yq nodejs
```

I set my proxy parameters using:

```
npm config set proxy http://my.domain.name:port
npm config set https-proxy http://my.domain.name:port
```

When doing `npm install` I get the following error:

```
...
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.7.1.tgz
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
...
```

I've checked similar posts but without any success:
[Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)
[npm behind a proxy fails with status 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773509/npm-behind-a-proxy-fails-with-status-403)

Please let me know if you have any idea on this one, best

Comment: npm install -g npm@3.10.10

Comment: Didn't work neither...

Comment: Remove the _auth entry from .npmrc file

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
export https_proxy=http://my.domain.name:port
export http_proxy=http://my.domain.name:port
```

Comment: leave it export from bash alias

Comment: Here is the end of my log file:```3558 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.7.1.tgz
3558 verbose stack     at res.buffer.catch.then.body (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:104:15)
3558 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
3559 verbose statusCode 403
3560 verbose pkgid acorn@5.7.13562 verbose Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
3563 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
3564 verbose node v10.16.3```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve my problem. The proxy settings defined by our admin didn't allow connections to https://registry.npmjs.org/. I had to define an exception to that particular address in my windows 10 proxy settings.
Thanks for your help